# Story about zombies fighting humans, believing they are humans fighting zombies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, zombie

A story starts with scene of humans assaulting a zombie nest in a mansion. They enter the building killing zombies, who cry some absurd. Among the zombies there was even a woman zombie pregnant with a baby zombie. We view the scene from the eyes of one of the stormtroopers.

As the story unfolds, it becomes clear that the "zombies" from the mansion are actually normal people. And the attacking "humans" are actually zombies, who got infected with a superhuman virus, declared themselves "real humans" and are eager to spread the virus to the whole population out of good intentions.

Please help me identify it.

Comment: This reminds me of a short story from one of the early Permuted Press zombie anthologies, but which one it was is escaping me at the minute

Comment: Sounds like the "men against fire" dark mirror episode. Maybe based on this story?

Comment: The story is definitely older than the Dark Mirror, so maybe. But, alas, my fast search found no claims that the episode was based on any zombie story.